# print database with printf in haskel

Tags: haskell, haskell-platform

something is wrong with my printf method . i am trying to print all the movies in the testDatabase. is the problem coming from the format characters i used in printf?

```
import Prelude
import Data.Char
import Data.Int
import Text.Printf

    -- Types
type Title = String
type Actor = String
type Cast = [Actor]
type Year = Int
type Fan = String
type Fans = [Fan]
type Period = (Year, Year)
    type Database = [Film]

testDatabase :: Database
testDatabase = [("The Gunman", ["Idris Elba", "Sean Penn", " Javier Bardem"], 2015,["Garry", "Dave", "Zoe", "Kevin", "Emma"]),
                ("The Shawshank Redemption", ["Tim Robbins", "Morgan Freeman", "Bob Gunton"],1994, ["Bill", "Jo", "Garry", "Kevin", "Olga", "Liz"]),
                ("The Dark Knight", ["Christian Bale", "Heath Ledger","Aaron Eckhart"], 2008, ["Zoe","Heidi", "Jo", "Emma", "Liz", "Sam", "Olga", "Kevin", "Tim"]),
                ("Inception", ["Leonardo DiCaprio", "Ellen Page"], 2010, ["Jo", "Emma", "Zack", "Olga", "Kevin"])]



printFilms :: Database -> IO()
printFilms [] = putStrLn "There are no films in the database"
printFilms filmList = sequence_ [printf("|%-s| |%-20s| |%2d| |%.1f|\n") title cast year fans | (title, cast, year, fans) <- filmList]




 No instance for (IsChar [Char]) arising from a use of `printf'
Possible fix: add an instance declaration for (IsChar [Char])
In the expression:
  printf ("|%s| |%-20s| |%2d| |%.1f|") title cast year fans
In the first argument of `sequence_', namely
  `[printf ("|%s| |%-20s| |%2d| |%.1f|") title cast year fans |
      (title, cast, year, fans) <- filmList]'
In the expression:
  sequence_
    [printf ("|%s| |%-20s| |%2d| |%.1f|") title cast year fans |
       (title, cast, year, fans) <- filmList]
```

Comment: The best rule of thumb for using `printf` in Haskell is "Don't use `printf` in Haskell." It's weird, it's a bit slow, and if you break it you get to keep both pieces. Sure, you can use it from time to time if you want, but there are usually better ways.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that `cast` and `fans` are lists of `String`s, not `String`s themselves. `%s` only supports single strings.  The error message is slightly confused by `printf`'s internal type magic, but essentially tells that it wants a `Char` rather than a `String = [Char]`.

You need to convert those lists to how you want them to get printed yourself. Something like

```
printFilms filmList = sequence_
    [printf("|%-s| |%-20s| |%2d| |%.1f|\n") title (unwords cast) year (unwords fans)
    | (title, cast, year, fans) <- filmList]
```

should allow you to get it to compile, although you probably want to replace `unwords` (at least the first one) with your own subformatting functions.